# perturbation of an audio/video decoding execution trace with gstreamer

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am a new comer in gstreamer community and i have a pipeline to decode and trace a .mp4 file.

```
gst-launch --gst debug=filesrc:7,queue:7,audioconvert:7,audioresample:7,qtdemux:7,faad:7,ffmpeg:7,audioresample:7,audioconvert:7,autoaudiosink:7,autovideosink:7,  filesrc location=...! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink > file1
```

I inserted the "identity" component to disturb the decoding, and effectively, i saw images which became very slow and sound disappeared.
I used this command:

```
gst-launch --gst debug=filesrc:7,queue:7,audioconvert:7,audioresample:7,qtdemux:7,faad:7,ffmpeg:7,audioresample:7,audioconvert:7,autoaudiosink:7,autovideosink:7,  filesrc location=...! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! identity sleep-time=1000000 ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink > file2
```

The first time i did this execution, two new functions appeared in file2,

(i)  **gst_ffmpegdec_chain...'skipping...'**,

(ii) **gst_ffmpegdec_video_frame...'Dropping..'**

I assumed that the meaning is that some data were dropped or something else

However, since many days, i use the same pipelines, with the same video to decode; i obtain the same bad visualization, but any new function in file 2 :(
the only difference is the number of occurrence of the functions below:

*gst_ffmpegdec_update_qos:...'update*  558 times in one case

*gst_ffmpegdec_update_qos:...'update*  4 times in the other case

I don't know why i am unable to produce again a disturbed trace with **'skipping..'** and **'dropping..'**

My questions are:

1- have you any idea about the meaning of the above functions?

2- Do you know any other component useful to disturb a A/V decoding processing?

Thank you for any reply

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but [Sirannon](http://sirannon.atlantis.ugent.be/) is a nice tool to create degraded transmissions of video streams, e.g. with packet loss.

Comment: @slhck Thank you for the link. However, my problem is that, i want to create a degraded transmission, but with a gstreamer pipeline. I would also want to have more informations on particular functions of Gtreamer :(